# How to add default fontSize to the Text in react native given adjustsFontSizeToFit is set to true?

Tags: react-native

I have the following code:

```
        <Text
          fontSize={100}
          adjustsFontSizeToFit
          numberOfLines={1}
        >{`$${amount}`}
        </Text>
```

This works fine, and scales the font as the amount increases, however the font size that is set at the beginning is very small - seems like `fontSize={100}` doesnt have any effect. Any ideas on what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You should add minimumFontScale (range 0.01 to 1.0), this is a fraction of your fontSize which will be used as minimum value